# Blank space when using ScrollView Activity in combination with adjustPan

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, adjustpan

My Linear Layout was taking too much space. So I decided to put it inside a ScrollView.

The layout has an EditText at the bottom for user input. To make the layout resize itself in AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity I put:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

It was OK for when I just had a Linear Layout, but now in combination with Scroll View I get a blank space, I think Android is trying to make space for the keyboard.

Layout.xml:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    ...

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</ScrollView>
```

[Before clicking keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PecN4.png)

[After clicking keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yofv.png)

Comment: use android:fillViewport="true" in your ScrollView

Comment: @MilanPansuriya wow thanks it worked! If you'd like submit an answer and I'll marked it as correct.

Comment: I had added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with following code

```
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        ...

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just as a side note for anyone reading:

I'm not sure if 

            android:isScrollContainer="false"

is necessary.